# NSNotificationCenter Adding or Removing UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification

Tags: objective-c

When using NSNotificationCenter's `-addObserver:selector:name:object:` or `-removeObserver:name:object:` with `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification` I receive an `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS code=1, address=0x0` on iOS 6.

I was using the following in `-viewWillAppear:` and `-viewWillDisappear:`

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(preferredFontSizeChanged:) name:UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    }

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    }
```

Additionally, note that `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification` is declared as such:

```
    UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

Which resolves to:

```
    #define UIKIT_EXTERN extern __attribute__((visibility ("default")))
```

Comment: Even in the most basic test useage? Can you give some context? do you know anything about the error from googling? Can you post examples of your code?

Comment: I've updated the post to include sample functions, note that calling `-removeObserver:name:object:` even when an object isn't registered is fine, basically, nothing happens.  You'll see this error with other constants that didn't exist in the version of iOS you're using (i.e. `NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName` in iOS 6)

Comment: Good work, how did you discover this?

Comment: Typically, one wouldn't make this mistake (include a feature for an iOS version that didn't support it), however the error isn't that descriptive if you end up finding it in someone else's code.  When searching for an answer I couldn't find anything leading me to the correct solution so after some trial and error I figured I'd post here in case anyone was looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, constants in the iOS SDK are declared as `extern NSString`.  The `extern` keyword is a contract stating that the memory for this will be allocated in another compilation unit.  Thus, in iOS 6, that notification type did not exist, so the bad access was due to the string not being allocated.